# How to make visible only certain portion of area in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay

Please see the following image. I want to be able to specify polygon/polyline so that the only area covered by it is visible. So far I have found methods to specify overlay so that specific portion on google maps is overlayed. I want the exactly opposite.

[image]

I tried adding a rectangle overlay over the current visible area to get the greyed out effect. Then I added the polygon overlay. My idea was if I add transparent polygon, it should reveal the map below it. It didn't work though. Any idea on how this can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing specific state of a country on gmap highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022368/showing-specific-state-of-a-country-on-gmap-highlighted/14022551#14022551) (the fusion table example doesn't seem to be working anymore, but it can be fixed)

Comment: I have seen that question which asks about specific state or country. What I am looking at is if I provide data points, is there a way to achieve it? I assume since I can draw rectangles, I should be able to draw an overlay with a hole.

Comment: That example just makes a hole which happens to be shaped like the state of Virginia.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this problem could be similar to [I want to create a Donut with Javascript API V3(Empty space inside like a hole)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846529/i-want-to-create-a-donut-with-javascript-api-v3empty-space-inside-like-a-hole).

See also [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wofup/1/edit).

You have to define two paths "in different directions". Outer path could be defined using coordinates from `map.getBounds()`. Inner path is your polygon.